# What are these white spots on the leaves of my fig tree?

Tags: diseases, pests, fungus, figs, mildew

I have a fig tree in my flat and some white spots have appeared and get more and more numerous and spread more and more over the leaves. It is not removable when rubbing with a tissue.

I can't find what it is, it does not seem to be common on fig tree! I'm suspecting mildew but it does not look like [this](https://www.dreamstime.com/plant-diseases-damage-white-genoa-fig-leaf-downy-mildew-powdery-rust-ventral-side-upper-image143838246) exactly or [that](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/54890/diagnosing-white-fuzz-on-kale-is-this-powdery-mildew). It also look like the results of the move of an  tiny worm inside the leave, but it is not so similar.

Also, the down face of the leave is brown where the white spots are located on the up side (see picture).

Any idea what it is from the picture below please?

Additional information:

- I regularly water the plant with vermicomposting juice
- The tap water is not especially mineralized here
- the soil is covered with marble pebbles

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These white spots are the damages produced by thrips. Actually, on one of the question images, white/transparent larva can be spotted:
[image]

The kind of damages changes with plants (see [2](http://ephytia.inra.fr/en/Contents/view/23157/Tropileg-Thrips)), and I have found that thrips are commun on fig tree, but the images are very similar to what can be produced sometimes by thrips on the up-side of the aubergine leaves (see this [picture](http://ephytia.inra.fr/en/I/38156/Thrips-Aubergine1)) or on the down-side of bean plant leaves (see this [picture](http://ephytia.inra.fr/en/I/38162/Thrips-Haricot1)).

Now, both larvae (white/transparent) and adult (black) thrips can be seen on the leaves: [image].

Insecticide spray can be made from oil and soap, see [here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/pesticides/homemade-soap-spray.htm).
To know more about thrips, see [here](http://ephytia.inra.fr/en/Contents/view/23157/Tropileg-Thrips).

Answer (score 0):

White spots on the leaves of the leaf fig may be a sign that the water you're using may be too hard. The white spots are essentially mineral residue... If youre using tap water heavily mineralized......Distilled water is always best for any houseplant.

Comment: My tap water is not heavily mineralized, however, it made me think that I covered the soil with marble pebbles and this may release minerals when I water the plants?  These pebbles release a "powder" when you put water on it.

Comment: Another hypothesis: I use soil from vermicompost and I also water with vermicomposting juice... but I guess this is not heavily mineralized.

Comment: Limestone ( marble) stays in soil unless dissolved by water and carried deeper.